# Error message about citation when using Lyx with Jabref

Tags: lyx, jabref

This is my first post.

I am trying to insert a citation in Lyx 2.3.5.2 from my database in Jabref 4.3.1. but the PDF does automatically generate and instead an error message comes up. I don't understand what they mean or how to fix them. If I allow LyX to produce a PDF despite the errors, the citation displays oddly, although it displays properly in JabRef itself. I have explained my process and error messages in the attached pictures.

[image: adding the Bibtex database]
[image: adding citation]

[image: Jabref citation]
[image: Error]

I suspect it has to do with the Spanish characters. If that is the case, it is especially important to fix it because (1) I am using international references and (2) part of my document will be written in German.

Hoping you can help me get back on track.

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: Just in case =: is your bib engine `bibtex` or `biber`?

Comment: the bibliography generation processor in LyX is set to default

Comment: JabRef uses unicode for such things as accents or other characters. I suggest trying to do a right click on the author field -> Convert -> Unicode to Latex. This will escape the critical unicode chars in a latex compatible way

Comment: @ChristophS - many thanks, it works now! :)